# Need some interface that generate fake device token to test push notification

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on push notification module at server side that will send push notification to mobile device.

As I am backend developer only, I need some online portal or similar kind of service that generate fake device token and I as a developer can use that device token and send notification on it. So that portal will display me notification text and other payload info.

I try to search things online but no luck. I have also asked to many mobile developer and my colleagues for this. They don't have any idea for this.

I am not sure that this kind of service is available yet or not. 
So thought, will try to ask genius people of this forum.

Thanks in advance.